# Get soundManager soundId from class using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, soundmanager2

I am using bar-ui js of soundmanager.

```
<div id="sm2-99943" class="sm2-bar-ui content compact flat full-width playlist full-width-player ">
    <div class="bd sm2-main-controls">
        <div class="sm2-inline-element sm2-button-element">
            <div class="sm2-button-bd" style="background: transparent url(http://support.simplepodcaster.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/podcast_channel_artwork-150x150.png) repeat scroll 0% 0% / cover ;">
                <div id="spp-player-background"> </div>
                <a href="#play" class="sm2-inline-button play-pause">Play / pause</a>
                <div class="eq">
                    <span class="bar bar-1"></span>
                    <span class="bar bar-2"></span>
                    <span class="bar bar-3"></span>
                    <span class="bar bar-4"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sm2-inline-element sm2-inline-status progressbar" style="padding-right:0px !important;">
            <div class="sm2-playlist">
                <div class="sm2-playlist-target" style="max-width: 100% !important;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="sm2-progress">
                <div class="sm2-progress-bd">
                    <div class="sm2-progress-track">
                        <div class="sm2-progress-bar1" style="display:none;"></div>
                        <div class="sm2-progress-bar"></div>
                        <div class="sm2-progress-ball">
                            <div class="icon-overlay"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="sm2-row">
                    <div class="sm2-inline-time1" style="display:none;">0:00</div>
                    <div class="sm2-inline-time">0:00</div>
                    <div class="sm2-inline-duration">0:00</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sm2-inline-element sm2-button-element sm2-menu">
            <div class="sm2-button-bd">
                <a href="#menu" class="sm2-inline-button menu">menu</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bd sm2-playlist-drawer sm2-element">
        <div class="sm2-playlist-wrapper">
            <ul class="sm2-playlist-bd">
                <li><a href="https://traffic.libsyn.com/secure/hmourra/HaniPodcast1_-_Introduction.mp3?dest-id=201638">Episode 1 - Introduction</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://traffic.libsyn.com/secure/hmourra/HaniPodcast2_-_Tools_To_Grow.mp3?dest-id=201638">Episode 2 - How To Start Podcasting</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://traffic.libsyn.com/secure/hmourra/SRP-thankyou.mp3?dest-id=201638">Episode 5 - Thank you!</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://traffic.libsyn.com/secure/hmourra/input.mp3?dest-id=201638">Episode 6</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://traffic.libsyn.com/secure/hmourra/episode6.mp3?dest-id=201638">2nd Episode 7</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://traffic.libsyn.com/secure/hmourra/Episode8.mp3?dest-id=201638">  Episode 10 - Blogging vs Podcasting</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://traffic.libsyn.com/secure/hmourra/Episode9.mp3?dest-id=201638">Episode 11 - Video vs Audio</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://traffic.libsyn.com/secure/hmourra/output.mp3?dest-id=201638">Episode 12 - Social Sharing Your Content</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://traffic.libsyn.com/secure/hmourra/hani2.mp3?dest-id=201638">Episode 13 - Growing Your Audience</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://traffic.libsyn.com/secure/hmourra/ep15.mp3?dest-id=201638">Episode 15 - Blogging for Leads</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://traffic.libsyn.com/secure/hmourra/ep16.mp3?dest-id=201638">Episode 16 - How To Get More iTunes Reviews</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://traffic.libsyn.com/secure/hmourra/ep17.mp3?dest-id=201638">Episode 17 - "Growing Your Email List on Autopilot"</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://traffic.libsyn.com/secure/hmourra/ep18.mp3?dest-id=201638">JUP 014 | Alexander Dahms: Mehrwert für andere statt Gewinndenken</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://traffic.libsyn.com/secure/hmourra/Iron_Horse.mp3?dest-id=201638">Episode 18</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://traffic.libsyn.com/secure/hmourra/Smoking_Gun.mp3?dest-id=201638">Episode 19 - New & Noteworthy</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://traffic.libsyn.com/secure/hmourra/Iron_Horse_copy.mp3?dest-id=201638">Episode 21 - Beliefs -> Decisions -> Outcomes</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://traffic.libsyn.com/secure/hmourra/WisdomTrek-Podcast-Day-597mixdown.mp3?dest-id=201638">Episode 22 - Publishing to Facebook</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://traffic.libsyn.com/secure/hmourra/ep22.mp3?dest-id=201638">Episode 24 - Repurposing Your Content</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://traffic.libsyn.com/secure/hmourra/test.mp3?dest-id=201638">Episode 26 - \Backslash /Frontslash To Facebook</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://traffic.libsyn.com/secure/hmourra/combined_This-is-the-title-with-an-emoji1523041021218.mp3?dest-id=201638">This is the title with an emoji</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have many players so what i need.

I want to select sound id from html class using jQuery...

I that possible ???

Like i am using content class in the above code so i can apply some custom changes that..

Update

See here are many players

```
http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/bar-ui/
```

And here is example of soundmanager2 code

```
var mySoundObject = soundManager.createSound({
    // optional id, for getSoundById() look-ups etc. If omitted, an id will be generated.
    id: 'mySound',
    url: '/audio/mysoundfile.mp3',
    // optional sound parameters here, see Sound Properties for full list
    volume: 50,
    autoPlay: true,
    whileloading: function() {
        console.log(this.id + ' is loading');
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you need to get the ID of the songs or of the player?

Comment: Could you add a fiddle for your code? I can't see any JavaScript code in your question.

Comment: @myfunkyside Yes i need to get the ID of the song of the player with the html class. Because i have many players in my page like at content section, sidebar, footer, So i have to get the ID of content section player and apply some Javascript to them

Comment: So where is the ID of the song in HTML codes above? What would be the output you expected from the code above if it has enough information?

Comment: Please see now i just updated some more informations here

Comment: What do you expect output would be in the HTML you provided?

Comment: I need to get this id from player class using javascript or jquery id: 'mySound',

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) since we can get any ID you want in HTML code you provided above.

Comment: When soundmanager2 create sound with this code soundManager.createSound({   if we add in this object id:"something" then we know what is id of this object. But if we did not mention soundmanager create id like "sound0", "sound1"

Comment: Now see this our site http://support.simplepodcaster.com/clammr-it-sample/ you can see two players on there. One in content and one in sidebar.... I just want get id one of the player which is in content section

Comment: Use console and write command window.soundManager.soundIDs;

Comment: you will get all ids which created by soundmanager but i want get one of player which is in content area

Comment: Can you provide a link to a demo of the page? let's see what we are looking at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like to make your ID available through the DOM, I'd suggest setting a data attribute in the `whileLoading` function like so:

```
var mySoundObject = soundManager.createSound({
id: 'mySound',
url: '/audio/mysoundfile.mp3',
// optional sound parameters here, see Sound Properties for full list
volume: 50,
autoPlay: true,
whileloading: function() {
    jQuery(_Element_Selector_You_Want_To_Bind_To_).data('sound-id', this.id)
}
});
```

Then afterward, you can retrieve that ID from the element with `jQuery(_Element_Selector_You_Want_To_Bind_To_).data('sound-id')`

(Since I generally avoid jQuery, compulsory vanilla solution is `document.querySelector(selector).setAttribute('data-sound-id', this.id)`
`document.querySelector(selector).getAttribute('data-sound-id')`
)

Comment: Well, that's also an approach. Though for this particular purpose I wouldn't use the `whileloading` event, since it's supposed to "fire at a regular interval when a sound is loading and new data has been received" (http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/#sm-config). It's better to use `onload(boolean:success)` where you can also check out whether the loading was successful at all

Comment: Cool, yeah that sounds like a better place to put it. I don't really know anything about this particular library so I was just going off of what's here.

Comment: I did not able to select the sound-id with jQuery until i press play button

Answer (score 0):

There is a special property dom storing all DOM objects of a player which for instance you can get through an expression `window.sm2BarPlayers[0].dom` according to the code of the bar-ui library you demonstrate in your example (it in turn exploits the soundmanager library).

As far as I understood, you're looking for the connection between `SMSound` (which you obtain through `window.soundManager.getSoundById('sound0')`) and the player object I mentioned. This connection is existent and it's kept in a private variable for the player (it's a closure in terms of JS):

```
exports = {
      on: null,
      actions: actions,
      dom: dom,
      playlistController: playlistController
    };
    soundObject = makeSound(playlistController.getURL());
```

The `exports` variable is later returned and that's what you have at your fingertips, whereas `soundObject` is closed inside. Though there seems to be a trick to accomplish your task as the code reveals: both your sound and its player have the same url and that's how you can find the connection. In other words, here is the approach:

```
var url = window.soundManager.getSoundById('sound0').url; //get the url of a sound
var player = window.sm2BarPlayers.find(function(p) { return p.playlistController.getURL() == url });
// Here you can use p.dom property where its DOM elements are kept and pass them to jQuery to build other search queries you need
```

To conclude, having the player DOM objects, you can later determine whether it's in the content area or somewhere else by means of standard JS selectors or jQuery ones. If you need some elaboration on how to tackle the last task, let me know in the comments.